# Detect "Clone Mode" display setup

Tags: windows, multiple-monitors

How can I determine if my displays are in "Clone Mode" without using either COPP (Computer Output Protection Protocol) or OPM (Output Protection Protocol) on Windows?

Vista solution:

```
hMonitor = MonitorFromWindow (HWND_DESKTOP, MONITOR_DEFAULTTOPRIMARY);
bSuccess = GetNumberOfPhysicalMonitorsFromHMONITOR (hMonitor,  &dwMonitorCount);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I assume you've already tried EnumDisplayMonitors() and it didn't work. So if that returns a single HMONITOR for each set of cloned displays, you could compare this set of results to the result of EnumDisplayDevices(). Devices returned by EnumDisplayDevices() that *are* attached to the desktop but *aren't* returned by EnumDisplayMonitors() should be clones.

Comment: When I have clone monitor, EnumDisplayMonitors() give me 1, and EnumDisplayDevices() which are flagged with DISPLAY_DEVICE_ATTACHED_TO_DESKTOP give me 0. Same results when external or second monitor is unplugged...

Comment: Isn't there a way to do this with QueryDisplayConfig() CCD paths? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-querydisplayconfig