# How to determine if a monitor is connected or desktop cloned?

Tags: .net, vb.net, winapi

I'm developing a program in VB.NET where I need to set a defined configuration depending on the state of dual monitors.

I'm not able to determine if a monitor is disconnected or its own display is a clone of primary display.

I am using `"user32.dll"` windows api to get information about displays and devices.

I am using `EnumDisplayDevices(...)` and I get info into DEVMODE and `DISPLAY_DEVICE` structures, but `DISPLAY_DEVICE.StateFlags` (they are DisplayDeviceStateFlags), give me a flag value of 0 for Clone or Disconnected monitor statuses

Through `EnumDisplayMonitors(...)` I get same result.

And with the last approach, iterating through `Screen.AllScreens` I get same results, only a screen if external monitor is disconnected or it is clone of a primary desktop...

So, what function (or struct) could give me the info about if a external monitor is connected to PC or it has desktop cloned?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect "Clone Mode" display setup](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/80103/detect-clone-mode-display-setup)

Comment: Yes, my question seems to be duplicate. I have tried its approach but it doesn't solve my problem...